# MacBook Boot Camp problem with installation Windows 10

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I have this error during the partitioning stage during the installation of Windows with Boot Camp

[image: Screenshot of Boot Camp Assistant giving an error while partitioning the drive]

I tried to check Time Machine backup to turn off, updated macOS to the latest version, and checked the partition in Disk Utility.

What should I do to fix it to install Windows 10?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning that it might take a long time. You really don't want to interrupt the process - that would be dangerous. The time to check your Time Machine is up to date would have been before you started this operation.

Comment: After last step I get a message for installation failure and all steps return back. My time machine is turn off. Do you have any idea for success installation ?

Comment: We really need to know the exact error message, the precise Mac model, current OS & version of bootcamp.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Problem solved with valid and formal ISO which download from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with valid and orginal ISO of Windows، download from Microsoft.

Comment: to make this useful to others, can you add download details and a link?